# Why it's impossible to change camera viewport rect while using pixelperfect camera in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, viewport

Why it's impossible to change camera viewport rect while using pixelperfect camera in unity?
Is there any specific reason to prevent viewport rect parameter changes?

Is there any way to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, couple minutes after I asked a question i figured it out, and found a solution.

It looks like pixel perfect camera script checks every frame if `m_Internal.useOffscreenRT` is set to true, if not it does change vieport rect to default parameters.

So i changed the script, and now it stores choosen viewport rect from camera on awake, and set it to camera every time it needs to, instead of default vieport rect (0,0,1,1);

Here is updated code if someone ever needs that:

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;

namespace UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Pixel Perfect Camera component ensures your pixel art remains crisp and clear at different resolutions, and stable in motion.
    /// </summary>
    [DisallowMultipleComponent]
    [AddComponentMenu("Rendering/2D/Pixel Perfect Camera (Experimental)")]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
    [MovedFrom("UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.LWRP")] public class PixelPerfectCamera : MonoBehaviour, IPixelPerfectCamera
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Match this value to to the Pixels Per Unit values of all Sprites within the Scene.
        /// </summary>
        public int assetsPPU { get { return m_AssetsPPU; } set { m_AssetsPPU = value > 0 ? value : 1; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// The original horizontal resolution your Assets are designed for.
        /// </summary>
        public int refResolutionX { get { return m_RefResolutionX; } set { m_RefResolutionX = value > 0 ? value : 1; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Original vertical resolution your Assets are designed for.
        /// </summary>
        public int refResolutionY { get { return m_RefResolutionY; } set { m_RefResolutionY = value > 0 ? value : 1; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to have the Scene rendered to a temporary texture set as close as possible to the Reference Resolution,
        /// while maintaining the full screen aspect ratio. This temporary texture is then upscaled to fit the full screen.
        /// </summary>
        public bool upscaleRT { get { return m_UpscaleRT; } set { m_UpscaleRT = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to prevent subpixel movement and make Sprites appear to move in pixel-by-pixel increments.
        /// Only applicable when upscaleRT is false.
        /// </summary>
        public bool pixelSnapping { get { return m_PixelSnapping; } set { m_PixelSnapping = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to crop the viewport with black bars to match refResolutionX in the horizontal direction.
        /// </summary>
        public bool cropFrameX { get { return m_CropFrameX; } set { m_CropFrameX = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to crop the viewport with black bars to match refResolutionY in the vertical direction.
        /// </summary>
        public bool cropFrameY { get { return m_CropFrameY; } set { m_CropFrameY = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to expand the viewport to fit the screen resolution while maintaining the viewport's aspect ratio.
        /// Only applicable when both cropFrameX and cropFrameY are true.
        /// </summary>
        public bool stretchFill { get { return m_StretchFill; } set { m_StretchFill = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ratio of the rendered Sprites compared to their original size (readonly).
        /// </summary>
        public int pixelRatio
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode)
                {
                    if (m_UpscaleRT)
                        return m_Internal.zoom * m_Internal.cinemachineVCamZoom;
                    else
                        return m_Internal.cinemachineVCamZoom;
                }
                else
                {
                    return m_Internal.zoom;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Round a arbitrary position to an integer pixel position. Works in world space.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position"> The position you want to round.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The rounded pixel position.
        /// Depending on the values of upscaleRT and pixelSnapping, it could be a screen pixel position or an art pixel position.
        /// </returns>
        public Vector3 RoundToPixel(Vector3 position)
        {
            float unitsPerPixel = m_Internal.unitsPerPixel;
            if (unitsPerPixel == 0.0f)
                return position;

            Vector3 result;
            result.x = Mathf.Round(position.x / unitsPerPixel) * unitsPerPixel;
            result.y = Mathf.Round(position.y / unitsPerPixel) * unitsPerPixel;
            result.z = Mathf.Round(position.z / unitsPerPixel) * unitsPerPixel;

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find a pixel-perfect orthographic size as close to targetOrthoSize as possible. Used by Cinemachine to solve compatibility issues with Pixel Perfect Camera.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetOrthoSize">Orthographic size from the live Cinemachine Virtual Camera.</param>
        /// <returns>The corrected orthographic size.</returns>
        public float CorrectCinemachineOrthoSize(float targetOrthoSize)
        {
            m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode = true;

            if (m_Internal == null)
                return targetOrthoSize;
            else
                return m_Internal.CorrectCinemachineOrthoSize(targetOrthoSize);
        }

        [SerializeField] Rect defaultRect = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        [SerializeField] int    m_AssetsPPU         = 100;
        [SerializeField] int    m_RefResolutionX    = 320;
        [SerializeField] int    m_RefResolutionY    = 180;
        [SerializeField] bool   m_UpscaleRT;
        [SerializeField] bool   m_PixelSnapping;
        [SerializeField] bool   m_CropFrameX;
        [SerializeField] bool   m_CropFrameY;
        [SerializeField] bool   m_StretchFill;

        Camera m_Camera;
        PixelPerfectCameraInternal m_Internal;
        bool m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode;

        internal bool isRunning
        {
            get
            {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                return (Application.isPlaying || runInEditMode) && enabled;
#else
                return enabled;
#endif
            }
        }

        internal FilterMode finalBlitFilterMode
        {
            get
            {
                if (!isRunning)
                    return FilterMode.Bilinear;
                else
                    return m_Internal.useStretchFill ? FilterMode.Bilinear : FilterMode.Point;
            }
        }

        internal Vector2Int offscreenRTSize
        {
            get
            {
                if (!isRunning)
                    return Vector2Int.zero;
                else
                    return new Vector2Int(m_Internal.offscreenRTWidth, m_Internal.offscreenRTHeight);
            }
        }

        // Snap camera position to pixels using Camera.worldToCameraMatrix.
        void PixelSnap()
        {
            Vector3 cameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.position;
            Vector3 roundedCameraPosition = RoundToPixel(cameraPosition);
            Vector3 offset = roundedCameraPosition - cameraPosition;
            offset.z = -offset.z;
            Matrix4x4 offsetMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(-offset, Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f));

            m_Camera.worldToCameraMatrix = offsetMatrix * m_Camera.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
        }

        void Awake()
        {
            m_Camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
            defaultRect = m_Camera.rect;
            m_Internal = new PixelPerfectCameraInternal(this);

            m_Internal.originalOrthoSize = m_Camera.orthographicSize;
        }

        void LateUpdate()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPaused)
#endif
            {
                // Reset the Cinemachine compatibility mode every frame.
                // If any CinemachinePixelPerfect extension is present, they will turn this on 
                // at a later time (during CinemachineBrain's LateUpdate(), which is 
                // guaranteed to be after PixelPerfectCamera's LateUpdate()).
                m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode = false;
            }
        }

        void OnBeginCameraRendering(ScriptableRenderContext context, Camera camera)
        {
            if (camera != m_Camera)
                return;

            var targetTexture = m_Camera.targetTexture;
            Vector2Int rtSize = targetTexture == null ? new Vector2Int(Screen.width, Screen.height) : new Vector2Int(targetTexture.width, targetTexture.height);

            m_Internal.CalculateCameraProperties(rtSize.x, rtSize.y);

            PixelSnap();

            if (m_Internal.useOffscreenRT)
                m_Camera.pixelRect = m_Internal.CalculateFinalBlitPixelRect(rtSize.x, rtSize.y);
            else
                m_Camera.rect = defaultRect;

            // In Cinemachine compatibility mode the control over orthographic size should
            // be given to the virtual cameras, whose orthographic sizes will be corrected to
            // be pixel-perfect. This way when there's blending between virtual cameras, we
            // can have temporary not-pixel-perfect but smooth transitions.
            if (!m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode)
            {
                m_Camera.orthographicSize = m_Internal.orthoSize;
            }

            UnityEngine.U2D.PixelPerfectRendering.pixelSnapSpacing = m_Internal.unitsPerPixel;
        }

        void OnEndCameraRendering(ScriptableRenderContext context, Camera camera)
        {
            if (camera == m_Camera)
                UnityEngine.U2D.PixelPerfectRendering.pixelSnapSpacing = 0.0f;
        }

        void OnEnable()
        {
            RenderPipelineManager.beginCameraRendering += OnBeginCameraRendering;
            RenderPipelineManager.endCameraRendering += OnEndCameraRendering;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying)
                UnityEditor.EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += OnPlayModeChanged;
#endif
        }

        internal void OnDisable()
        {
            RenderPipelineManager.beginCameraRendering -= OnBeginCameraRendering;
            RenderPipelineManager.endCameraRendering -= OnEndCameraRendering;

            m_Camera.rect = defaultRect;
            m_Camera.orthographicSize = m_Internal.originalOrthoSize;
            m_Camera.ResetWorldToCameraMatrix();

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying)
                UnityEditor.EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged -= OnPlayModeChanged;
#endif
        }

#if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD || UNITY_EDITOR
        // Show on-screen warning about invalid render resolutions.
        void OnGUI()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying && !runInEditMode)
                return;
#endif

            Color oldColor = GUI.color;
            GUI.color = Color.red;

            Vector2Int renderResolution = Vector2Int.zero;
            renderResolution.x = m_Internal.useOffscreenRT ? m_Internal.offscreenRTWidth : m_Camera.pixelWidth;
            renderResolution.y = m_Internal.useOffscreenRT ? m_Internal.offscreenRTHeight : m_Camera.pixelHeight;

            if (renderResolution.x % 2 != 0 || renderResolution.y % 2 != 0)
            {
                string warning = string.Format("Rendering at an odd-numbered resolution ({0} * {1}). Pixel Perfect Camera may not work properly in this situation.", renderResolution.x, renderResolution.y);
                GUILayout.Box(warning);
            }

            var targetTexture = m_Camera.targetTexture;
            Vector2Int rtSize = targetTexture == null ? new Vector2Int(Screen.width, Screen.height) : new Vector2Int(targetTexture.width, targetTexture.height);

            if (rtSize.x < refResolutionX || rtSize.y < refResolutionY)
            {
                GUILayout.Box("Target resolution is smaller than the reference resolution. Image may appear stretched or cropped.");
            }

            GUI.color = oldColor;
        }
#endif

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        void OnPlayModeChanged(UnityEditor.PlayModeStateChange state)
        {
            // Stop running in edit mode when entering play mode.
            if (state == UnityEditor.PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode)
            {
                runInEditMode = false;
                OnDisable();
            }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that make it no longer pixel perfect?

Comment: @Nikaas From what i see after some tests, it works exactly the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

As it was written in the answer above, this camera changes the transforms of the current camera, all that had to be done was to tell the pixel perfect to the camera to take the transforms of the usual camera

```
namespace UnityEngine.U2D
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Pixel Perfect Camera component ensures your pixel art remains crisp and clear at different resolutions, and stable in motion.
    /// </summary>
    [DisallowMultipleComponent]
    [AddComponentMenu("Rendering/Pixel Perfect Camera")]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
    public class PixelPerfectCamera : MonoBehaviour, IPixelPerfectCamera
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Match this value to to the Pixels Per Unit values of all Sprites within the Scene.
        /// </summary>
        public int assetsPPU { get { return m_AssetsPPU; } set { m_AssetsPPU = value > 0 ? value : 1; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// The original horizontal resolution your Assets are designed for.
        /// </summary>
        public int refResolutionX { get { return m_RefResolutionX; } set { m_RefResolutionX = value > 0 ? value : 1; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Original vertical resolution your Assets are designed for.
        /// </summary>
        public int refResolutionY { get { return m_RefResolutionY; } set { m_RefResolutionY = value > 0 ? value : 1; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to have the Scene rendered to a temporary texture set as close as possible to the Reference Resolution,
        /// while maintaining the full screen aspect ratio. This temporary texture is then upscaled to fit the full screen.
        /// </summary>
        public bool upscaleRT { get { return m_UpscaleRT; } set { m_UpscaleRT = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to prevent subpixel movement and make Sprites appear to move in pixel-by-pixel increments.
        /// Only applicable when upscaleRT is false.
        /// </summary>
        public bool pixelSnapping { get { return m_PixelSnapping; } set { m_PixelSnapping = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to crop the viewport with black bars to match refResolutionX in the horizontal direction.
        /// </summary>
        public bool cropFrameX { get { return m_CropFrameX; } set { m_CropFrameX = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to crop the viewport with black bars to match refResolutionY in the vertical direction.
        /// </summary>
        public bool cropFrameY { get { return m_CropFrameY; } set { m_CropFrameY = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true to expand the viewport to fit the screen resolution while maintaining the viewport's aspect ratio.
        /// Only applicable when both cropFrameX and cropFrameY are true.
        /// </summary>
        public bool stretchFill { get { return m_StretchFill; } set { m_StretchFill = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ratio of the rendered Sprites compared to their original size (readonly).
        /// </summary>
        public int pixelRatio
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode)
                {
                    if (m_UpscaleRT)
                        return m_Internal.zoom * m_Internal.cinemachineVCamZoom;
                    else
                        return m_Internal.cinemachineVCamZoom;
                }
                else
                {
                    return m_Internal.zoom;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Round a arbitrary position to an integer pixel position. Works in world space.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position"> The position you want to round.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The rounded pixel position.
        /// Depending on the values of upscaleRT and pixelSnapping, it could be a screen pixel position or an art pixel position.
        /// </returns>
        public Vector3 RoundToPixel(Vector3 position)
        {
            float unitsPerPixel = m_Internal.unitsPerPixel;
            if (unitsPerPixel == 0.0f)
                return position;

            Vector3 result;
            result.x = Mathf.Round(position.x / unitsPerPixel) * unitsPerPixel;
            result.y = Mathf.Round(position.y / unitsPerPixel) * unitsPerPixel;
            result.z = Mathf.Round(position.z / unitsPerPixel) * unitsPerPixel;

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find a pixel-perfect orthographic size as close to targetOrthoSize as possible. Used by Cinemachine to solve compatibility issues with Pixel Perfect Camera.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetOrthoSize">Orthographic size from the live Cinemachine Virtual Camera.</param>
        /// <returns>The corrected orthographic size.</returns>
        public float CorrectCinemachineOrthoSize(float targetOrthoSize)
        {
            m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode = true;

            if (m_Internal == null)
                return targetOrthoSize;
            else
                return m_Internal.CorrectCinemachineOrthoSize(targetOrthoSize);
        }

        [SerializeField]
        int m_AssetsPPU = 100;

        [SerializeField]
        int m_RefResolutionX = 320;

        [SerializeField]
        int m_RefResolutionY = 180;

        [SerializeField]
        bool m_UpscaleRT = false;

        [SerializeField]
        bool m_PixelSnapping = false;

        [SerializeField]
        bool m_CropFrameX = false;

        [SerializeField]
        bool m_CropFrameY = false;

        [SerializeField]
        bool m_StretchFill = false;

        Camera m_Camera;
        PixelPerfectCameraInternal m_Internal;
        bool m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode;

        // Snap camera position to pixels using Camera.worldToCameraMatrix.
        void PixelSnap()
        {
            Vector3 cameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.position;
            Vector3 roundedCameraPosition = RoundToPixel(cameraPosition);
            Vector3 offset = roundedCameraPosition - cameraPosition;
            offset.z = -offset.z;
            Matrix4x4 offsetMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(-offset, Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f));

            m_Camera.worldToCameraMatrix = offsetMatrix * m_Camera.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
        }

        void Awake()
        {
            m_Camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
            m_Internal = new PixelPerfectCameraInternal(this);

            m_Internal.originalOrthoSize = m_Camera.orthographicSize;
            m_Internal.hasPostProcessLayer = GetComponent("PostProcessLayer") != null;   // query the component by name to avoid hard dependency

            if (m_Camera.targetTexture != null)
                Debug.LogWarning("Render to texture is not supported by Pixel Perfect Camera.", m_Camera);
        }

        void LateUpdate()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPaused)
#endif
            {
                // Reset the Cinemachine compatibility mode every frame.
                // If any CinemachinePixelPerfect extension is present, they will turn this on 
                // at a later time (during CinemachineBrain's LateUpdate(), which is 
                // guaranteed to be after PixelPerfectCamera's LateUpdate()).
                m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode = false;
            }

            m_Internal.CalculateCameraProperties(Screen.width, Screen.height);

            // To be effective immediately this frame, forceIntoRenderTexture should be set before any camera rendering callback.
            // An exception of this is when the editor is paused, where we call LateUpdate() manually in OnPreCall().
            // In this special case, you'll see one frame of glitch when toggling renderUpscaling on and off.
            m_Camera.forceIntoRenderTexture = m_Internal.hasPostProcessLayer || m_Internal.useOffscreenRT;
        }

        void OnPreCull()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            // LateUpdate() is not called while the editor is paused, but OnPreCull() is.
            // So call LateUpdate() manually here.
            if (UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPaused)
                LateUpdate();
#endif

            PixelSnap();

            if (m_Internal.pixelRect != Rect.zero)
                m_Camera.pixelRect = m_Camera.pixelRect; //m_Internal.pixelRect;
            else
                m_Camera.rect = m_Camera.pixelRect; //new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

            // In Cinemachine compatibility mode the control over orthographic size should
            // be given to the virtual cameras, whose orthographic sizes will be corrected to
            // be pixel-perfect. This way when there's blending between virtual cameras, we
            // can have temporary not-pixel-perfect but smooth transitions.
            if (!m_CinemachineCompatibilityMode)
            {
                m_Camera.orthographicSize = m_Internal.orthoSize;
            }
        }

        void OnPreRender()
        {
            // Clear the screen to black so that we can see black bars.
            // Need to do it before anything is drawn if we're rendering directly to the screen.
            if (m_Internal.cropFrameXOrY && !m_Camera.forceIntoRenderTexture && !m_Camera.allowMSAA)
                GL.Clear(false, true, Color.black);

            PixelPerfectRendering.pixelSnapSpacing = m_Internal.unitsPerPixel;
        }

        void OnPostRender()
        {
            PixelPerfectRendering.pixelSnapSpacing = 0.0f;

            // Clear the screen to black so that we can see black bars.
            // If a temporary offscreen RT is used, we do the clear after we're done with that RT to avoid an unnecessary RT switch. 
            if (m_Camera.activeTexture != null)
            {
                Graphics.SetRenderTarget(null as RenderTexture);
                GL.Viewport(new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, Screen.width, Screen.height));
                GL.Clear(false, true, Color.black);
            }

            if (!m_Internal.useOffscreenRT)
                return;

            RenderTexture activeRT = m_Camera.activeTexture;
            if (activeRT != null)
                activeRT.filterMode = m_Internal.useStretchFill ? FilterMode.Bilinear : FilterMode.Point;

            m_Camera.pixelRect = m_Internal.CalculatePostRenderPixelRect(m_Camera.aspect, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        void OnEnable()
        {
            if (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying)
                UnityEditor.EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += OnPlayModeChanged;
        }
#endif

        internal void OnDisable()
        {
            m_Camera.rect = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            m_Camera.orthographicSize = m_Internal.originalOrthoSize;
            m_Camera.forceIntoRenderTexture = m_Internal.hasPostProcessLayer;
            m_Camera.ResetAspect();
            m_Camera.ResetWorldToCameraMatrix();

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying)
                UnityEditor.EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged -= OnPlayModeChanged;
#endif
        }

#if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD || UNITY_EDITOR
        // Show on-screen warning about invalid render resolutions.
        void OnGUI()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying && !runInEditMode)
                return;
#endif

            Color oldColor = GUI.color;
            GUI.color = Color.red;

            Vector2Int renderResolution = Vector2Int.zero;
            renderResolution.x = m_Internal.useOffscreenRT ? m_Internal.offscreenRTWidth : m_Camera.pixelWidth;
            renderResolution.y = m_Internal.useOffscreenRT ? m_Internal.offscreenRTHeight : m_Camera.pixelHeight;

            if (renderResolution.x % 2 != 0 || renderResolution.y % 2 != 0)
            {
                string warning = string.Format("Rendering at an odd-numbered resolution ({0} * {1}). Pixel Perfect Camera may not work properly in this situation.", renderResolution.x, renderResolution.y);
                GUILayout.Box(warning);
            }

            if (Screen.width < refResolutionX || Screen.height < refResolutionY)
            {
                GUILayout.Box("Screen resolution is smaller than the reference resolution. Image may appear stretched or cropped.");
            }

            GUI.color = oldColor;
        }
#endif

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        void OnPlayModeChanged(UnityEditor.PlayModeStateChange state)
        {
            // Stop running in edit mode when entering play mode.
            if (state == UnityEditor.PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode)
            {
                runInEditMode = false;
                OnDisable();
            }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

I changed these lines:

```
if (m_Internal.pixelRect != Rect.zero)
                m_Camera.pixelRect = m_Camera.pixelRect; //m_Internal.pixelRect;
            else
                m_Camera.rect = m_Camera.pixelRect; //new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```